# What does it mean when 'Community' accepts or rejects a suggested edit?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, community-user

Sometimes when I look at my suggested edits I see some which have been rejected by [Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) even when accepted by other users. How can this be? I thought [Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) was just a background, automated process. Does it really have veto over suggested edits?

Comment: Hovering over "Community" in the "marked as duplicate" box will also tell you why Community can close a question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when a reviewer chooses "Reject & Edit", or "Improve Edit".
Then Community is credited with the binding Reject or Approve vote, and the reviewer's edit becomes the new edit.